# UserManager helper method in the template AccountController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, asp.net-identity-2

The template AccountController class (VS 2013 Update 2) includes this code:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

So here we have a nifty `ApplicationUserManager` helper property that returns a saved ApplicationUserManager object (if the second constructor is called) or the ApplicationUserManager fetched from the Owin pipeline if the parameterless constructor was called.

Question: Does anything ever call the constructor that passes in an ApplicationUserManager object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not by default. But if you start using a DI-framework you can setup the DI framework to inject your controller with any constructor, in your case the **ApplicationUserManager**.

By **default** a MVC-controller need the **empty constructor** to work, but if you use a DI-framework you can configure that to **inject** any type of constructor. The advantage of using constructor injection is the possibility to **mock** every dependent object.

If you want to use any DI framework I should recommend AutoFac, https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration

Comment: I was wondering about this same thing. I set some breakpoints inside both of those AccountController constructors, and it did seem like the one accepting the userManager instance *was* getting called by something at some point. Interestingly, I think they were both getting called in the same request, not sure exactly what was happening but I thought it was strange nonetheless. (If memory serves correctly, can't actually verify this right now.)

Comment: It's not possible to get the both constructors called during the same request with the code above. It can only happen if you in the empty constructor call the other one.